# The textfield tableNum doesn't pass String into tableLabel from another class

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get the input from the textfield (tableNum) and pass it into a label (tableLabel) from another class. I am not sure how to exactly pass the value  from the textfield to the label. 
Any help would be appreciated.

//Extraction from first class

```
num_Table = new JTextField();

num_Table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                                  
             char c=e.getKeyChar();
            if(!(Character.isDigit(c) ||      (c==KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)||c==KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){
            e.consume();                                                                        
            }
        }
});
num_Table.setBounds(334, 161, 83, 26);
contentPane.add(num_Table);
num_Table.setColumns(10);

num_TableSub_Btn = new JButton("Submit");
num_TableSub_Btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        num_Table.setText("");
    }
});
num_TableSub_Btn.setBounds(487, 161, 83, 29);
contentPane.add(num_TableSub_Btn);
```

//Extraction from second class

```
tableLabel = new JLabel("New label");
tableLabel.setBounds(16, 6, 61, 16);
contentPane.add(tableLabel);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `numTable` as a parameter to the constructor of your second class. Add a [`DocumentListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to `numTable`, not a `KeyListener`. In your `DocumentListener`, call `setText()` to update the label.

```
numTable.addDocumentListener(new MyDocumentListener());
…
class MyDocumentListener implements DocumentListener {

    public void insertUpdate() {
        update();
    }
    public void removeUpdate() {
        update();
    }
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {}

    public void update() {
        tableLabel.setText(numTable.getText());
    }
}
```