# Trying to pass the table number between two classes

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to pass the table number from the restaurant class into tableLabel which is in the Menu page class. When the code is running the tableLabel returns null. Any help would be appreciated to enable the code when running to return a number in the tableLabel.

Extract from Restaurant Class

```
public class Restaurant extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField restaurant_Txt;
private JTextField num_Diners;
private JTextField num_Diners_Txt;
private JTextField table_Num_Txt;
private JTextField num_Table;
private JButton num_TableSub_Btn;
private JButton proceed_Menu_Btn;
private JButton MyDocumentListener;
MenuPage parent;

public static String tableNumber;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Restaurant frame = new Restaurant();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}



public Restaurant() {
    super("Restaurant");
    parent = new MenuPage();
    initGUI();

   num_Table = new JTextField("NewUser", 10);
}

public void initGUI() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 640, 310);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    table_Num_Txt = new JTextField();
    table_Num_Txt.setEditable(false);
    table_Num_Txt.setText("Table number ?");
    table_Num_Txt.setBounds(145, 164, 112, 26);
    contentPane.add(table_Num_Txt);
    table_Num_Txt.setColumns(10);


    num_Table = new JTextField("");
    num_Table.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                          
        if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {                                                         
                tableNumber = num_Table.getText();      

            }
    }
    });

    num_Table.setBounds(334, 161, 83, 26);
    contentPane.add(num_Table);
    num_Table.setColumns(10);

}
}
```

Extract from Menu Page class

```
   tableLabel = new JLabel("  : " + Restaurant.tableNumber);
    tableLabel.setBounds(16, 6, 61, 16);
    contentPane.add(tableLabel);
```

Comment: can't find the variable tableLabel in your source code

Comment: tableLabel is in the Menu Page Class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The textfield tableNum doesn't pass String into tableLabel from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36426773/the-textfield-tablenum-doesnt-pass-string-into-tablelabel-from-another-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a stupid question, but are you sure you are pressing enter when being inside the num_Table field inside your GUI since the variable is set when this happens. Also you should probably pass it via the constructor to MainPage, not as a static variable.

Comment: Yes, I have pressed enter after typing in the number for num_Table and it still returns null.

Comment: `if (e.getKeyCode() == 10) {                                                         
                tableNumber = num_Table.getText();      
}`
Try debugging this line by a simple System.out.println(...) and check if the if condition is met.

Comment: I changed Key typed to Key pressed and the value now returns into the label. Thanks guys.